# react useEffect cleanup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand this hook : https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/
The hook looks like this :

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

// Usage
function App() {
  // Create a ref that we add to the element for which we want to detect outside clicks
  const ref = useRef();
  // State for our modal
  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  // Call hook passing in the ref and a function to call on outside click
  useOnClickOutside(ref, () => setModalOpen(false));

  return (
    <div>
      {isModalOpen ? (
        <div ref={ref}>
           Hey, I'm a modal. Click anywhere outside of me to close.
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)}>Open Modal</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

// Hook
function useOnClickOutside(ref, handler) {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const listener = event => {
        // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
        if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
          return;
        }

        handler(event);
      };

      document.addEventListener('mousedown', listener);
      document.addEventListener('touchstart', listener);

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', listener);
        document.removeEventListener('touchstart', listener);
      };
    },
    // Add ref and handler to effect dependencies
    // It's worth noting that because passed in handler is a new ...
    // ... function on every render that will cause this effect ...
    // ... callback/cleanup to run every render. It's not a big deal ...
    // ... but to optimize you can wrap handler in useCallback before ...
    // ... passing it into this hook.
    [ref, handler]
  );
}
```

My question is, at what point will the cleanup function in my useEffect run. I read "when it's component unmounts". But I dont exactly know what this means, what component do they mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at what point will the cleanup function in my useEffect run

From [`React Docs - When exactly does React clean up an effect?`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)

> React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we
> learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This
> is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before
> running the effects next time.

In short, cleanup function runs when:

- Component unmounts
- Before running the `useEffect` again

> I read "when it's component unmounts". But I dont exactly know what this means, what component do they mean.

They mean the component in which you use this hook. In your case, that's the `App` component.

Comment: Worth noting that that means: If `ref` or `handler` changes, the cleanup callback gets run and the effect function gets run again. `ref` won't change assuming it comes from `useRef`, but unless `handler` is memoized (via `useCallback` or `useMemo` or similar), it'll frequently change.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good point and this is also mentioned in a comment inside the `useOnClickOutside` hook, just before the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Does the app component ever unmount though ?

Comment: @Kevin.a One case where it can unmount is when you render another component into the root container. When a component is removed from the DOM, it is considered to have unmounted.